# Saving files into colab.research.google.com from local drive

Tags: python

I am using this code to upload files into the code lab.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
  name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

but I need to save it into a specific directory inorder to load them later using sklearn.datasets.load_files ...

```
train_data = load_files(train_dir,encoding='utf-8', decode_error='ignore', random_state=2018)
test_data = load_files(test_dir,encoding='utf-8', decode_error='ignore', random_state=2018)
```

Thank you for helping me in advance